# size classes issue for dynamic UI elements

Tags: ios, size-classes

I have used size classes for UI elements on the storyboard , but what for the ui elements I've created dynamically.

Suppose I have a **UILabel** with frame 10,10,200,25... I shows different on different devices , how to main that via size classes , i assume we manually have to set the missing constraint but if somebody could point me out to a proper explanation .

```
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|"                                                                             
options:kNilOptions
metrics:nil
views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set programatically constraints then you need to add following constraints into UILabel and UIView in which UILabel is added.

lblName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   NSDictionary *usageViewsDictionary = @{@"lblControl":lblName};
[lblName addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[lblControl(25)]"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                              views:usageViewsDictionary]];
        [lblName addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[lblControl(200)]"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                              views:usageViewsDictionary]];
  [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[lblControl]"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:usageViewsDictionary]];
        [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[lblControl]"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:usageViewsDictionary]];